# Flash AS3 print a movieclip larger than stage, and offscreen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a fla with a stage size of width:750 x height:375. 
The fla contains a movieclip named "cert_mc", which is supposed to represent a certificate you would print off.

Off to the right side of the stage I have the same movieclip, it's just been duplicated and rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise. It has an instance name of "printCert_mc".

The printCert_mc movieclip needs to print to a size 8.5 x 11 piece of paper.

The problem I am encountering is that printCert_mc will only print when it is visible on the stage. If I move it onto the stage, it only prints 750x375 of the printCert_mc movieclip.

This is my code:

```
function onReleaseHandler(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();

    var printArea:Rectangle;
    var printHeight:Number;
    var printY:int = 0;

    if (printJob.start()) {

        if (printCert_mc.width < printJob.pageWidth) {
            printCert_mc.width = printJob.pageWidth;
            printCert_mc.scaleY = printCert_mc.scaleX;
        }

        /* Store reference to print area in a new variable! Will save on scaling calculations later... */
        printArea = new Rectangle(0,0,printJob.pageWidth / printCert_mc.scaleX,printJob.pageHeight / printCert_mc.scaleY);

        printJob.addPage(printCert_mc,printArea);
        printJob.send();
    }
}
```

It would be preferable if printCert_mc remained off the screen and was still printable and filled an 8.5 x 11 sheet of paper.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR ASKING THIS.
There's incredibly little information on printing in Flash. I'm running into a similar problem in which I need to print a movieclip that's half-off-screen, and only half of it is printing.

This is quite the conundrum.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what i would do is  a "bitmapdata" copy of the Movie Clip store as an image by what ever size you like then print that image.

i personally haven't printed anything from flash, saving the image would be plausible